# what is the best practice in codes which has multiple display flex

Tags: flexbox, dry

How can I avoid repeating (display:flex, justify-content:center , aign-items:center) in my codes?I want to use them but I don't want to repeat my self (DRY rule).
is there any way to define a variable or something which contains those three lines? (WITHOUT USING SASS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a template class for all flexboxes in your code:

```css
.flexbox {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox navbar-flexbox">*some text*</div>
<div class="flexbox content-flexbox">*some text*</div>
```